# Fail to use multiple sortable lists using a drag-and-drop library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

im working with some [library for drag-and-drop ng2-dnd](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd) (angular 2 library), and for one list its working Wonderfull for me, its a very simple implementation too, it looks like this:

```
<md-content>

  <h1 align="center">{{title}}</h1>

  <div *ngIf="showingListOne">
    <div dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="listOneToDisplay | async">
      <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#item of listOneToDisplay | async; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
        ID: {{item.id}} <p></p> name: {{item.name}}
      </div>
    </div><br><br>
    <div class="list-bg">Current Matcher {{matcherBulksToDisplay | async | json}}</div>
  </div>


  <div *ngIf="showingListTwo">
    <div dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="listTwoToDisplay | async">
      <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#item of listTwoToDisplay | async; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
        ID: {{item.id}} <p></p> age: {{item.age}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>Current Expedite {{expediteBulksToDisplay | async | json}}</div>
  </div>


  <div *ngIf="showingListThree">
    <div dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="listThreeToDisplay | async">
      <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#item of listThreeToDisplay | async; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
        ID: {{item.id}} <p></p> age: {{item.age}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>Current Cropping {{croppingBulksToDisplay | async | json}}</div>
  </div>

</md-content>
```

I have 3 buttons that present 3 different lists on the same component, but each on its time.

does anyone knows why would if only work with the first list?
the only difference is that in the 2nd and 3rd lists im pulling `age` instead of name.

its driving me crazy cause its the same code but only the first list is sortable and the other not, maybe its something with the library?

please help :/

Comment: The data is being presented properly in all three lists, but you cannot reorder the 2nd or 3rd list?

Comment: @wolfhoundjesse exactly buddy!

Comment: @wolfhoundjesseif you can find me the problem I will be so thankfullllll

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit]** Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n2GWbu?p=info).

Our network is having some issues today, so I was unable to create a plunkr for you. If you fork [this plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/JbG8Si) and paste the following over the code in app.ts, you should see it in action.

You can accomplish what you want with **useFactory**. The problem is that you have three lists trying to use one service, a singleton. Try this:

1. import proved from @angular/core
2. import SortableComponent from ng2-dnd/ng2-dnd
3. add the provide function below to your providers array. Now each of your lists will create its own instance of the service
4. Don't forget to add drop zones to your separate lists, or you can actually tangle them all together.

   ```
   import {Component, provide} from '@angular/core';
   import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
   import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

   import {DND_PROVIDERS, DND_DIRECTIVES, SortableComponent} from 'ng2-dnd/ng2-dnd';

   @Component({
       selector: 'app',
     directives: [DND_DIRECTIVES],
     providers: [DND_PROVIDERS, provide(SortableComponent {useFactory: () => return new SortableContainer()})],
       template: `
   <div class="container">
       <div> 
       <h1 align="center">{{title}}</h1>  


     <div *ngIf="showingListTwo">
       <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone1']" [sortableData]="listTwoToDisplay">
         <div class="list-bg" style="background:pink;border:1px solid blue" *ngFor="#item of listTwoToDisplay; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
           ID: {{item.id}} <p></p> age: {{item.age}} 
         </div>
       </div>

     </div>


     <div *ngIf="showingListThree">  
       <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone2']" [sortableData]="listThreeToDisplay">
         <div class="list-bg" style="background:yellow;border:1px solid blue" *ngFor="#item of listThreeToDisplay; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
           ID: {{item.id}} <p></p> age: {{item.age}}
         </div>
       </div>

     </div>

   </div>`
   })
   export class AppComponent {

       showingListOne = true;
       showingListTwo = true;
       showingListThree = true;

       listOneToDisplay = [
           {id:1, name: 'Frank'},
           {id:2, name: 'Bill'},
           {id:3, name: 'Bob'},
           {id:4, name: 'Sue'},
           ];

       listTwoToDisplay = [
           {id:1, age: 13},
           {id:2, age: 22},
           {id:3, age: 32},
           {id:4, age: 19},
           ];

       listThreeToDisplay = [
           {id:1, age: 23},
           {id:2, age: 32},
           {id:3, age: 34},
           {id:4, age: 12},
           ];


       constructor() {
       }

   }



   bootstrap(AppComponent);
   ```

I hope this helps!

Comment: `providers: [DND_PROVIDERS, provide(SortableComponent {useFactory: () => return new SortableContainer()})],` this line dosent compile man, im using typescript, `SortableContainer` say "invalid number of args, expecting 5" and some other stuff in that line dosent work for me :/

Comment: I added a working plunker for you. Also, it might make a difference as to which version of angular you are using.

Comment: im using angular 2.0.0-beta.15, unfortunally I cant upgrade it currently

Comment: In that case, another temporary fix that I haven't tested could be to change dnd.sortable.ts where ng2-dnd is installed in your node_modules folder. 

Find the line: @Directive({ selector: '[dnd-sortable]' })

Change it to: @Directive({ selector: '[dnd-sortable]', providers: [DragDropSortableService, DragDropService] })

That might enable you to create more than one instance.